# Alt+tab alternative that makes all windows visible, filling the screen

Tags: macos, window

A couple of years ago I saw (I think on OSX) a command, like <kbd>alt+tab</kbd> on Windows, that resized (and un-minimize) all opened windows making all them visible on desktop, filling the screen, like a puzzle.

I tried to do some research on web, but I was unable to find something like that. I suppose it was made possible thought some add-on, some external window manager. I'd really like to implement it into my Windows 8.1.

Does anybody give me some suggestion on how to do it? The name of a software, a useful Google search query, anything! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're needing is 'window tiling'.

Starting with OSX 10.2 Jaguar, the following can be used:

> F9 Key – Tile or un-tile all open windows (for quick selection and
>   access)
>
> F10 Key – Tile or un-tile all open windows in the currently active
>   (frontmost) application

Source: http://www.techlicious.com/tip/the-most-useful-mac-keyboard-shortcuts/